# How to format this string so that it can be recognized by Convert.ToDateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, formatting

I am given this whole string from database:

```
CCC_0293170118-10-2013-20-27-54.541
```

I had the substring so that I get `18-10-2013-20-27-54`, but it throws an error

I want to convert it to DateTime so that I can compare it with another DateTime with format like "{10/18/2013 8:28:46 PM} to get the time difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `"dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss"` format like;

```
string s = "18-10-2013-20-27-54";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
10/18/2013 8:27:54 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/KTTqmh)</kbd>.

Comment: Damn, less than a minute and you have a working demo link, +1 of course.

Comment: Thanks @Habib. I think this is the first answer of mine which gets more upvote than Jon's answer `:)`

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. It's just a value.

To parse a value such as "18-10-2013-20-27-54" you should use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) (or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx), if it's somewhat-expected that the data may be invalid). So something like:

```
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's important to specify the invariant culture here to ensure that the Gregorian calendar is used - if you use the "current system culture" then it could use a different default calendar system.

Comment: Thank you so much too, you have been a hero =)